# jqGrid - Add ms access like row navigation buttons

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

Are there any built in row navigation buttons in jqGrid which I can use? I tried looking on jqGrid Documentation and here on SO. Nothing seems to give me any solution even close.

Example of what I want.

[image: Access image]

**EDIT** The behaviour of these buttons would be like this. On pressing the next button the row below should be selected.

[image]

So when the user pressed the next button, the next row is selected till the end of rows are reached.

So are there any built in buttons to do so or do I have to write my own custom button? If so a heads up will be appreciated.

Comment: The default pager navigation buttons of jqGrid looks already almost like on the your picture. One can place the pager at the bottom of the grid, at the top of on the both places. The only difference to your picture is the field "1 of 31" which looks on jqGrid a little different. I'm not sure what is your exact requirement about the  navigation buttons.

Comment: Hi @Oleg. That's the pager you are talking about which is used to navigate through pages. I want row navigator buttons which when pressed will traverse up and down throughout the grid and select one row. I will update my question to explain you better.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var gn = grid.navGrid("#pager",{edit:false,add:false,del:false,search:false,refresh:false}); //where 'grid' is the grid object and '#pager' is the pager element.
gn.navButtonAdd("#pager",{
    id: "customButton",
    caption:"Next Row",
    onClickButton: function(){ 
        var selectedRow = grid.getGridParam('selrow');
        if (selectedRow == null) return;
        var ids = grid.getDataIDs();
        var index = grid.getInd(selectedRow);
        if (ids.length < 2) return;
        index++;
        if (index > ids.length) index = 1;
        grid.setSelection(ids[index - 1], true);
    }
});
```

Style the button based on your need.